# C# OpenTK QuickFont Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in QuickFont.dll

Tags: c#, opentk

While I am trying to figure out how to render a simple 2D text in OpenTK, I am constantly getting the error "Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in QuickFont.dll".
It is thrown at `QFontDrawing drawing = new QFontDrawing();` which makes no sense at all.

Anyone got any ideas on what it could be? I've been trying to find an answer but could'nt find anything useful. 
Tried it on 2 different computers incase of faulty RAM, but the error is still there.

If there's anything missing, feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: What .net framework are you using?

Comment: Did you solve this? Running into the same problem with 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 QuickFont packages.

Comment: @Austin I did not.. I have no clue what could be causing it so I decided to go with bitmap textures instead.